# С++ abstract return type

Tags: c++, oop

I have the following structure of classes:

```
struct A {
    virtual void function() = 0;
};
struct B : A {
    void function() override {
        // ...implementation...
    }
};
struct C {
    virtual A a() = 0;
};
struct D : public C {
    A a() {
        return B{};
    }
}
```

the main idea is: I do not really care what class will be returned from `D::a`, **the only property I want it to have is a `function()` member-function**. So I denoted the return type as the abstract class `A` which has this property as virtual, and then try to return `B` object which is derived from `A`. But this does not work, giving `error: invalid abstract return type`. Could you please suggest a way to achieve the desired effect in C++?

Comment: Read about polymorphism in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: You can't return an abstract type, and even if you somehow could, there would be nothing useful you'd be able to do with it. You could have `a()` return a pointer to a dynamically allocated object, instead, though there might be better designs depending on what you ultimately want to achieve.

Comment: How about templates?

Comment: And what is the *actual* problem you try to solve? Why do you "not really care what class will be returned from `D::a`"? If you tell us about the real and underlying problem you try to solve, then perhaps we can help you solve that directly instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't create objects of abstract types, you can create pointers of them. As Ayxan said, you can use also smart pointers, but I suggest you use `shared_ptr` because it's more comfortable.
2. Use `dynamic_cast` to convert `B` to `A`.
3. You forgot to add `;` to the end of the third struct.

Here is the correct code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    virtual void function() = 0;
};
struct B : A {
    void function() override {
        std::cout << "EEAAAHHHH\n";
    }
};
struct C {
    virtual A* a() = 0;
};
struct D : public C {
    A* a() {
        B *a = new B;
        A *b = dynamic_cast<A*>(a);

        return b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    A* a = d.a();

    a->function();
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile and run the code, you can see that the output is "EEAAAHHHH".
I'm happy to help you, and I wish you success.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is useless for up-casting. `dynamic_cast<B*>(a);` casts from `B*` to `B*`? Why?

Comment: In this code: `B *a = new B; A *b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a); return b;` the `dynamic_cast` is completely unnecessary. A pointer-to-derived can be assigned to a pointer-to-base without an explicit cast at all. Especially since you are casting the pointer to the same type as the pointer, which is redundant. That code can be simplify to just `return new B;` But, the caller must call `delete` on the returned pointer or else the `new`'ed object will be leaked.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is not suitable here, as it implies shared-ownership which is usually not the case. `unique_ptr` should be your default choice for the majority of cases.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, you can't do polymorphism with objects, because objects could have different sizes, and in C++ types have value semantics. You can, however, do polymorphism with references, and pointers. So your function could be:

```
A* a();
// or
A& a();
```

This does mean that you may have problems with ownership. You can also return a smart pointer instead:

```
unique_ptr<A> a();
```

Comment: Is there any way to make my structure better with the same or close result? The problem is: I am given with abstract class, and my task requires to return it, but it has no implementation, so I should return some object with implementation. Is there any solutions for this?

Comment: @AlexTeexone You simply cannot do dynamic polymorphism with non-reference-non-pointer types. You can use one of the solutions I show in the answer, or you may take an "out-parameter" like `void a(A& result);`. Here the parameter is a reference type, so it's fine.